# Entity framework multiple parents

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, azure

I have two models.

BdoSubSystem:

```
public class BdoSubSystem
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And BdoSystem:

```
public class BdoSystem
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BdoSubSystem> SubSystems { get; set; }
}
```

I used migration to create the tables automatically on Azure. The problem is that subsystem is not specific for each system, a subsystem may have multiple parents and can appear in more than one system. But in this way, each subsystem belongs to each system.

How can a subsystem appear in multiple systems?

Comment: Looks like you are looking for a many-to-many relationship, which is usually solved in a database with an extra table (e.g. Person, Address and PersonAddress) so that ever X can be linked to multiple Y while every Y can also be linked to multiple X. Last time I looked at EF it did not deal with this very well, even DB-first (navigation properties didnt work as expected). Hopefully somene can fill you in on how the ewest EF handles this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm looking for some tutorial with many-tomany relationship. I'll check if it helps me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good, thanks you all. The solution is to reference in subsystem and use [JsonIgnore]

```
public class BdoSubSystem
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<BdoSystem> SubSystems { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand, SubSystem is just a king of System that with a System as parent ?

If my sentence is true, you can use **Self Referencing**

```
public class BdoSystem
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentSystemId { get; set; }
    public virtual BdoSystem ParentSystem { get; set; }

}
```

However, if you want to have two seperates objects, you should add the **navigation propertie in both classes**

```
public class BdoSubSystem
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BdoSystem> Systems { get; set; }
}

public class BdoSystem
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BdoSubSystem> SubSystems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get your first answer. Because on your first example, the system doesn't have a collection of subsystem anymore.
Anyway, i'm looking for many-to-many relationship and I'll check if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Great, I checked some many to many tutorials and did exactly as is in your second example. Migration created another table on azure named "BdoSystemBdoSubSystem".
But now, serialization to JSON isn't working anymore, I guess that's because of the loop reference in each model. Is there a safe way to serialize this object?

Comment: The first solution is a tree and not a list. And as I see you found the solution for your problem. You can also disable Lazyloading, it will not load the navigation properties automaticaly anymore.